# Output redirect csv based on condition in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very large csv file that I would like to export part of based on a certain condition - I need to keep all columns but only export the part of the csv where `summary_id` > 92900.  How would one write this command in BASH?

```
$ head -n 10 snapshots.csv
id,station_id,status,available_bikes,available_docks,created_at,summary_id
32583548,465,Active,18,7,2015-12-12 12:40:07.325473,92982
32583549,466,Active,28,33,2015-12-12 12:40:07.330174,92982
32583550,467,Active,13,17,2015-12-12 12:40:07.334921,92982
32583551,468,Active,21,22,2015-12-12 12:40:07.339576,92982
32583552,469,Active,44,19,2015-12-12 12:40:07.344086,92982
32583553,470,Active,12,46,2015-12-12 12:40:07.34872,92982
32583554,471,Active,12,11,2015-12-12 12:40:07.353296,92982
32583555,472,Active,12,19,2015-12-12 12:40:07.357868,92982
32583556,473,Active,0,29,2015-12-12 12:40:07.362545,92982
```

Comment: `export part of the csv`? can you explain more on this? with how you want to do this, export as a variable? (which variable)

Comment: You can use: `awk -F, '$NF > 92900' file.csv > exported.csv`

Comment: thanks, what is `$NF` ?

Comment: `$NF` represents last field in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@anubhava got it completely right in his comment. `awk` is the tool to use here.

```
awk -F, '$NF > 92900' file.csv > exported.csv
```

Explanation-

`-F,` sets the delimiter to be a comma.

`$NF` is an inbuilt variable in `awk` which refers to the last column. You could also use `$7` in case you don't always have the last column as your field of interest.

A clearer way of writing the command would be-

```
awk -F, '{if ($NF > 92900) print $0}' file.csv > exported.csv
```

or

```
awk -F, '{if ($7 > 92900) print $0}' file.csv > exported.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, `awk` is probably the most suited for this task (see comment Anubhava), but because you asked how to do in BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat snapshots.csv |
while read line ; do
    value=${line##*,}
    if [ $value -gt 92900 ] ; then
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

The `${line##*,}` will remove everything from $line upto (incl) the last comma.

Comment: You are not reading from the file actually, fix it to make it valid, and the csv has comma separated values.